# Typescript complaining about "Parsing error: Enum member names cannot start with lowercase 'a' through 'z'"

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

In my typescript project a I have the following enum type:

```
export enum ModelAttributeTypes {
  binary = 'binary',
  binarySet = 'binarySet',
  bool = 'bool',
  list = 'list',
  map = 'map',
  number = 'number',
  numberSet = 'numberSet',
  string = 'string',
  stringSet = 'stringSet',
  _null = '_null'
}
```

My project does not compile with the error `Parsing error: Enum member names cannot start with lowercase 'a' through 'z'`.

I cannot update the enum type myself because it's being generated by a third party framework.

How can I disable this rule which complains about `Parsing error: Enum member names cannot start with lowercase 'a' through 'z'`.

Here are my my dev dependencies that relate to typescript:

```
      "@babel/cli": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.15.0",
    "@dazn/lambda-powertools-logger": "^1.28.1",
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^7.0.7",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^7.31.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.12",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^1.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.11.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^3.9.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
```

This is my `eslint` config.

```
{
  "plugins": ["jest-dom"],
  "extends": ["plugin:cypress/recommended", "plugin:jest-dom/recommended", "eslint:recommended"],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "rules": {
    "jest-dom/prefer-checked": "error",
    "jest-dom/prefer-enabled-disabled": "error",
    "jest-dom/prefer-required": "error",
    "jest-dom/prefer-to-have-attribute": "error",
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "max-len": ["warn", { "code": 120 }]
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true
  }
}
```

And my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom.iterable", "es2016.array.include", "es2017.object", "dom"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "ES6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types": ["cypress", "@testing-library/cypress"],
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "cypress/integration/auth.spec.js",
    "cypress/integration/home_page_spec.js",
    "cypress/integration/cypress_access_local_storage.js",
    "custom.back.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [".history/**/*"]
}
```

Can anyone help me with why I keep getting `Parsing error: Enum member names cannot start with lowercase 'a' through 'z'` and how I can fix it ?

Comment: Resolved, it was eslint who caused the error. Resolved by adding the file to `.eslintignore`

Comment: Could you please provide an answer?

Comment: can you delete this question as it was operator error and doesn't really help future people.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Resolved, it was eslint who caused the error. Resolved it by adding the file which was not conform to the rules to `.eslintignore`

Comment: This isn't really an answer

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is encountering this issue, I found another post here: [Eslint rises unexpected "EnumInvalidMemberName" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73068645/eslint-rises-unexpected-enuminvalidmembername-error) that helped me to resolve the issue. The solution  he posted was change the eslint configuration:

```
//.eslintrc
{
-  "parser": "babel-eslint"
+  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
}
```